# Regex isn't working, why?

Tags: regex

```
^(((\d{0,5}){1}|(\d{0,5}\.{1}(\d{0,5}){1})){1}[x]{1}((\d{0,5}){1}|(\d{0,5}\.{1}(\d{0,5}){1})){1})$
```

I want the regex to check if the string is 
(Either an Integer/Decimal)x(Either an Integer/Decimal) or Just one Integer/Decimal. The regex I wrote when I enter 2x or 2.5x , it should be false but it says that it is a match even though it doesn't have the second integer/decimal specified even though there is an 'x', If it was 2 or 2.5 without the x that would be fine.

Some examples of what I want it to accept:

```
3x1
12345.123451x12345.12345
.12345x.12345
00000.12345x1
3
4.12345
```

I don't want it to accept:

```
1x
1xx2
4fx34
```

I also don't want the numbers to be too large that is why I have {1} everywhere. The max I want it to be is 5 digits before and 5 after the decimal.

However it is returning true on the regex when I enter `2x` and that breaks my stored procedure I'm sending the data to. Acceptable entry would be `2` or `2x1`.

Comment: It is unclear what pattern you wan't to match. You should rephrase the question in a format that makes it crystal clear what your problem is.

Comment: What's with all the `{1}`s? That is noise that can be deleted.

Comment: I suggest playing around with [regex101](https://regex101.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there was a lot of unnecessary noise in your regex, as well as a lot of room for error due to the use of `{0,5}` which can match empty strings. So I did a little rewrite and came up with

```
^(?>\d{0,5}\.\d{1,5}|\d{1,5})(?:x(?>\d{0,5}\.\d{1,5}|\d{1,5}))?$
```

Please note first, that you could replace `{0,5}` with `*` and `{1,5}` with `+` if there isn't a real need for the limit to 5 digits. It will also not match your second example from the question, as it has 6 decimal numbers in the first number.

So lets break it down a bit:

- `^` is an anchor for the start of the string
- `(?>\d{0,5}\.\d{1,5}|\d{1,5})` is an atomic group matching either 0 to 5 digits followed by a dot followed by another 1 to 5 digits (decimal number) or 1 to 5 digits (integer). I used an atomic group in here to avoid unnecessary backtracking when the regex fails to match.
- `(?:x(?>\d{0,5}\.\d{1,5}|\d{1,5}))?` is an optional group matching the letter x followed by another number, following the same pattern as before.
- `$` is an anchor for the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches all but #2, which has 6 consecutive digits:

`^(((\d{0,5})|(\d{0,5}\.(\d{0,5})))[x ]((\d{0,5})|(\d{0,5}\.(\d{0,5}))))\s*$`

1. `{1}` is useless. I removed it all.
2. `.` needs to be escaped (`\.`) if you literally want to match a period
3. I used `\s*` (0 or more whitespace chars) to ensure it matches despite trailing whitespace. You may want to add one to the beginning.

---

I'm not sure what you're doing with all the capture groups. Consider using `(?:)` instead of `()` if you do not care about what's inside.

---

Edit: based on your clarification of what you are looking for, try:

`^(((\d{1,5}|\d{0,5}\.(\d{0,5})))(?:[x ]((\d{1,5}|\d{0,5}\.(\d{0,5})))))?\s*$`

Comment: Thank you, I would like it to not be okay if you enter '2x' as the format I want to accept is either 1 int/decimal multiplied by another int/decimal OR just one integer/decimal, so the '2x' should be false but that regex says that it is true. I am using Regex101.com